# database design on category of identity

Tags: database, database-design

So, I'm learning (and using) a database, and so far I think I'm understanding it

Today, a question arise on the following example:

I have a table with identities (for instance, objects, which have a name and a physical description and naturally a primary auto-increment integer index). And I have identities (e.g. persons) which interact with then).

Is there any way of categorizing these identities in my a database? For instance, assume a mechanic only interacts with a very specific set of those objects (tools, car pieces, etc). So, it would make sense to restrict any search by a mechanic on the objects to that set.

Any hints on what is the natural way (if any) to approach this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need a table category with an id and a description

An object can have many categories and a category can have many objects. So we are facing a [many to many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

You need a third table, that we call a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). This table would have the id of the category and the id of the object.

The design would look like this

```
Category
Id | Description

Object
Id | Description

Person
id | Type | ...

Categories_Objects
Id | CategoryId | ObjectId
```

Then if you want to select the objects for a mechanic which would be the category 1 (that's an example, you need to find the id first)

You would do a select like this

```
SELECT Object.Description 
FROM Object 
     INNER JOIN Categories_Objects ON Object.id = Categories_Objects.ObjectID 
WHERE CategoryID = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT Object.Description 
FROM Object 
     INNER JOIN Categories_Objects ON Object.id = Categories_Objects.ObjectID
     INNER JOIN Category ON Categories_Objects.CategoryId = Category.id
WHERE category.description = "Mechanic"
```

**Note:** If a person can use many categories of tools, you will need another junction table like this

```
Persons_Categories
ID | PersonID | CategoryID
```